# Why hibernate try to acquire more than one connection?

Tags: java, hibernate

My previous project I did was with hibernate 4.3 and didn't have any problems. This time I'm using hibernate 5.2. I'm facing issue when I get this error:

```
ERROR: Collection leak detected: there are 1 unclosed connections upon shutting down pool
```

After investigation I noticed that on `save` hibernate is trying to open 2 connections. Why? I was using always these settings, but never had issues before:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
```

**MainApp.java:**

```
package home.accounting;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

import home.accounting.DA.LanguagesDA;
import home.accounting.model.Languages;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        LanguagesDA.setMainApp(this);

        final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
                .build();
        try {
            sessionFactory = new MetadataSources( registry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
            LanguagesDA.save(new Languages("english","en"));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // The registry would be destroyed by the SessionFactory, but we had trouble building the SessionFactory
            // so destroy it manually.
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy( registry );
        }
    }

     /**
     * Initialises the root layout.
     */
    public void initRootLayout() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        sessionFactory.close();
    }
}
```

**LanguagesDA.java**:

```
package home.accounting.DA;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import home.accounting.MainApp;
import home.accounting.model.Languages;

public class LanguagesDA {

    private static MainApp mainApp;

    public static void save(Languages language) {
        Session sess = mainApp.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        System.out.println("Session opened!");
        Transaction tx = null;
         try {
             tx = sess.beginTransaction();
             sess.save(language);
             tx.commit();
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
             if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
             System.out.println(e);
             throw e;
         }
         finally {
             sess.close();
             System.out.println("Session closed!");
         }
    }

    public static void setMainApp(MainApp app) {
        mainApp = app;
    }
}
```

**Languages.java**:

```
package home.accounting.model;
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name="languages")
public class Languages {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="language_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="language_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="language_code")
    private String code;

    public Languages(){}

    public Languages(String name, String code){
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.sqlite.JDBC</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:src/home/accounting/DB/Accounting.sqlite</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">on_close</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</property>

        <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
        <mapping class="home.accounting.model.Languages"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**SQLiteDialect.java**:

```
/*
 * The author disclaims copyright to this source code.  In place of
 * a legal notice, here is a blessing:
 *
 *    May you do good and not evil.
 *    May you find forgiveness for yourself and forgive others.
 *    May you share freely, never taking more than you give.
 *
 */
package org.hibernate.dialect;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

import org.hibernate.JDBCException;
import org.hibernate.ScrollMode;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.AbstractAnsiTrimEmulationFunction;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.NoArgSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionTemplate;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.VarArgsSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.dialect.identity.IdentityColumnSupport;
import org.hibernate.dialect.identity.SQLiteDialectIdentityColumnSupport;
import org.hibernate.dialect.pagination.AbstractLimitHandler;
import org.hibernate.dialect.pagination.LimitHandler;
import org.hibernate.dialect.pagination.LimitHelper;
import org.hibernate.dialect.unique.DefaultUniqueDelegate;
import org.hibernate.dialect.unique.UniqueDelegate;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.RowSelection;
import org.hibernate.exception.DataException;
import org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException;
import org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException;
import org.hibernate.exception.spi.SQLExceptionConversionDelegate;
import org.hibernate.exception.spi.TemplatedViolatedConstraintNameExtracter;
import org.hibernate.exception.spi.ViolatedConstraintNameExtracter;
import org.hibernate.internal.util.JdbcExceptionHelper;
import org.hibernate.mapping.Column;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;

/**
 * An SQL dialect for SQLite 3.
 */
public class SQLiteDialect extends Dialect {
    private final UniqueDelegate uniqueDelegate;

    public SQLiteDialect() {
        registerColumnType( Types.BIT, "boolean" );
        //registerColumnType(Types.FLOAT, "float");
        //registerColumnType(Types.DOUBLE, "double");
        registerColumnType( Types.DECIMAL, "decimal" );
        registerColumnType( Types.CHAR, "char" );
        registerColumnType( Types.LONGVARCHAR, "longvarchar" );
        registerColumnType( Types.TIMESTAMP, "datetime" );
        registerColumnType( Types.BINARY, "blob" );
        registerColumnType( Types.VARBINARY, "blob" );
        registerColumnType( Types.LONGVARBINARY, "blob" );

        registerFunction( "concat", new VarArgsSQLFunction( StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "", "||", "" ) );
        registerFunction( "mod", new SQLFunctionTemplate( StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, "?1 % ?2" ) );
        registerFunction( "quote", new StandardSQLFunction( "quote", StandardBasicTypes.STRING ) );
        registerFunction( "random", new NoArgSQLFunction( "random", StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER ) );
        registerFunction( "round", new StandardSQLFunction( "round" ) );
        registerFunction( "substr", new StandardSQLFunction( "substr", StandardBasicTypes.STRING ) );
        registerFunction( "trim", new AbstractAnsiTrimEmulationFunction() {
            protected SQLFunction resolveBothSpaceTrimFunction() {
                return new SQLFunctionTemplate( StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "trim(?1)" );
            }

            protected SQLFunction resolveBothSpaceTrimFromFunction() {
                return new SQLFunctionTemplate( StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "trim(?2)" );
            }

            protected SQLFunction resolveLeadingSpaceTrimFunction() {
                return new SQLFunctionTemplate( StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "ltrim(?1)" );
            }

            protected SQLFunction resolveTrailingSpaceTrimFunction() {
                return new SQLFunctionTemplate( StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "rtrim(?1)" );
            }

            protected SQLFunction resolveBothTrimFunction() {
                return new SQLFunctionTemplate( StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "trim(?1, ?2)" );
            }

            protected SQLFunction resolveLeadingTrimFunction() {
                return new SQLFunctionTemplate( StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "ltrim(?1, ?2)" );
            }

            protected SQLFunction resolveTrailingTrimFunction() {
                return new SQLFunctionTemplate( StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "rtrim(?1, ?2)" );
            }
        } );
        uniqueDelegate = new SQLiteUniqueDelegate( this );
    }

    // database type mapping support ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    @Override
    public String getCastTypeName(int code) {
        // FIXME
        return super.getCastTypeName( code );
    }

    // IDENTITY support ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    private static final SQLiteDialectIdentityColumnSupport IDENTITY_COLUMN_SUPPORT = new SQLiteDialectIdentityColumnSupport();
    @Override
    public IdentityColumnSupport getIdentityColumnSupport() {
        return IDENTITY_COLUMN_SUPPORT;
    }

    // limit/offset support ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    private static final AbstractLimitHandler LIMIT_HANDLER = new AbstractLimitHandler() {
        @Override
        public String processSql(String sql, RowSelection selection) {
            final boolean hasOffset = LimitHelper.hasFirstRow( selection );
            return sql + (hasOffset ? " limit ? offset ?" : " limit ?");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean supportsLimit() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean bindLimitParametersInReverseOrder() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public LimitHandler getLimitHandler() {
        return LIMIT_HANDLER;
    }

    // lock acquisition support ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    @Override
    public boolean supportsLockTimeouts() {
        // may be http://sqlite.org/c3ref/db_mutex.html ?
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String getForUpdateString() {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsOuterJoinForUpdate() {
        return false;
    }

  /*
    @Override
  public boolean dropTemporaryTableAfterUse() {
    return true; // temporary tables are only dropped when the connection is closed. If the connection is pooled...
  }
  */

    // current timestamp support ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    @Override
    public boolean supportsCurrentTimestampSelection() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isCurrentTimestampSelectStringCallable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String getCurrentTimestampSelectString() {
        return "select current_timestamp";
    }

    // SQLException support ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    private static final int SQLITE_BUSY = 5;
    private static final int SQLITE_LOCKED = 6;
    private static final int SQLITE_IOERR = 10;
    private static final int SQLITE_CORRUPT = 11;
    private static final int SQLITE_NOTFOUND = 12;
    private static final int SQLITE_FULL = 13;
    private static final int SQLITE_CANTOPEN = 14;
    private static final int SQLITE_PROTOCOL = 15;
    private static final int SQLITE_TOOBIG = 18;
    private static final int SQLITE_CONSTRAINT = 19;
    private static final int SQLITE_MISMATCH = 20;
    private static final int SQLITE_NOTADB = 26;

    @Override
    public SQLExceptionConversionDelegate buildSQLExceptionConversionDelegate() {
        return new SQLExceptionConversionDelegate() {
            @Override
            public JDBCException convert(SQLException sqlException, String message, String sql) {
                final int errorCode = JdbcExceptionHelper.extractErrorCode( sqlException );
                if (errorCode == SQLITE_TOOBIG || errorCode == SQLITE_MISMATCH) {
                    return new DataException( message, sqlException, sql );
                }
                else if (errorCode == SQLITE_BUSY || errorCode == SQLITE_LOCKED) {
                    return new LockAcquisitionException( message, sqlException, sql );
                }
                else if ((errorCode >= SQLITE_IOERR && errorCode <= SQLITE_PROTOCOL) || errorCode == SQLITE_NOTADB) {
                    return new JDBCConnectionException( message, sqlException, sql );
                }

                // returning null allows other delegates to operate
                return null;
            }
        };
    }

    public ViolatedConstraintNameExtracter getViolatedConstraintNameExtracter() {
        return EXTRACTER;
    }

    private static final ViolatedConstraintNameExtracter EXTRACTER = new TemplatedViolatedConstraintNameExtracter() {
        @Override
        protected String doExtractConstraintName(SQLException sqle) throws NumberFormatException {
            final int errorCode = JdbcExceptionHelper.extractErrorCode( sqle );
            if (errorCode == SQLITE_CONSTRAINT) {
                return extractUsingTemplate( "constraint ", " failed", sqle.getMessage() );
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    // union subclass support ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    @Override
    public boolean supportsUnionAll() {
        return true;
    }

    // DDL support ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    @Override
    public boolean canCreateSchema() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasAlterTable() {
        // As specified in NHibernate dialect
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dropConstraints() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean qualifyIndexName() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAddColumnString() {
        return "add column";
    }

    @Override
    public String getDropForeignKeyString() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException( "No drop foreign key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect" );
    }

    @Override
    public String getAddForeignKeyConstraintString(String constraintName,
            String[] foreignKey, String referencedTable, String[] primaryKey,
            boolean referencesPrimaryKey) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException( "No add foreign key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect" );
    }

    @Override
    public String getAddPrimaryKeyConstraintString(String constraintName) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException( "No add primary key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect" );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsCommentOn() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsIfExistsBeforeTableName() {
        return true;
    }

  /* not case insensitive for unicode characters by default (ICU extension needed)
    public boolean supportsCaseInsensitiveLike() {
    return true;
  }
  */

    @Override
    public boolean doesReadCommittedCauseWritersToBlockReaders() {
        // TODO Validate (WAL mode...)
        return true;
    }

    public boolean doesRepeatableReadCauseReadersToBlockWriters() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsTupleDistinctCounts() {
        return false;
    }

    public int getInExpressionCountLimit() {
        // Compile/runtime time option: http://sqlite.org/limits.html#max_variable_number
        return 1000;
    }

    @Override
    public UniqueDelegate getUniqueDelegate() {
        return uniqueDelegate;
    }
    private static class SQLiteUniqueDelegate extends DefaultUniqueDelegate {
        public SQLiteUniqueDelegate(Dialect dialect) {
            super( dialect );
        }
        @Override
        public String getColumnDefinitionUniquenessFragment(Column column) {
            return " unique";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getSelectGUIDString() {
        return "select hex(randomblob(16))";
    }

    @Override
    public ScrollMode defaultScrollMode() {
        return ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY;
    }
}
```

**SQLiteDialectIdentityColumnSupport.java**:

```
package org.hibernate.dialect.identity;

public class SQLiteDialectIdentityColumnSupport extends IdentityColumnSupportImpl {
    @Override
    public boolean supportsIdentityColumns() {
        return true;
    }

  /*
    public boolean supportsInsertSelectIdentity() {
    return true; // As specified in NHibernate dialect
  }
  */

    @Override
    public boolean hasDataTypeInIdentityColumn() {
        // As specified in NHibernate dialect
        // FIXME true
        return false;
    }

  /*
    public String appendIdentitySelectToInsert(String insertString) {
    return new StringBuffer(insertString.length()+30). // As specified in NHibernate dialect
      append(insertString).
      append("; ").append(getIdentitySelectString()).
      toString();
  }
  */

    @Override
    public String getIdentitySelectString(String table, String column, int type) {
        return "select last_insert_rowid()";
    }

    @Override
    public String getIdentityColumnString(int type) {
        // return "integer primary key autoincrement";
        // FIXME "autoincrement"
        return "integer";
    }
}
```

My languages table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE "languages"(
language_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
language_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
language_code VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL)
```

By using `try catch` blocks I managed to get this line:

```
Session opened!
org.hibernate.HibernateException: The internal connection pool has reached its maximum size and no connection is currently available!
Jun 30, 2017 4:55:50 PM org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener end
INFO: Session Metrics {
    72982 nanoseconds spent acquiring 2 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

**Libraries used are**: `sqlite-jdbc-3.16.1.jar` and hibernate 5.2.10

Comment: It would be surprising if Hibernate were in fact opening two connections specifically in `save()`, and your metrics don't suggest that it is doing so.  In fact, your metrics suggest that the code you have presented is not involved in the issue you're asking about at all, because they show no activity that can be attributed to the `save()` and subsequent `commit()` -- in particular, no JDBC statements executed and no cache usage.

Comment: I know, also can't understand what's going on. I commented out all other code connecting to database, so currently this is the only place where I try to connect to database. No problems if using, `createNativeQuery()` method, just `save()`.

Comment: It sounds like you have already taken steps towards constructing a [mcve], but your question does not actually present one, and what it does present does not seem sufficient to inform an answer to the question.  I guess completeness would require code for setting up the session factory, preparing the entity object, invoking `CurrencyDA.save()`, and subsequently shutting down the session factory.  If you choose to provide a more complete example, please do not neglect the "minimal" and "verifiable" attributes in doing so.

Comment: I updated, should now be the full code that I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this issue by replacing `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`.